# Do migrate module migrations continue in background if terminal session ends?

Tags: 7, drush, migrations

I'm working on a migration that involves some long migration times - many hours to migrate some tables. I use the drush commands to perform my migrations, but often something happens in the middle. The window closes by accident, or I lose my Internet connection for a minute, whatever. When I open a new terminal and run 'drush ms' I see my migration marked "importing"... but is it really going to finish at some point?

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify an operating system in your question, so I'll assume it's Linux/OSX.

Really, this isn't specific to drush. An applications will be sent the `SIGHUP` signal when their parent terminal exits.

The very simplest way around that is to wrap your application in `nohup`, causing it to ignore the signal.

`nohup drush status`

However, that still leaves you without control of the application should your shell close.

A better solution, is to use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), which runs a terminal server in the background from which you can detach, and later reattach, and one or several terminals can keep running indefinitely.

You launch tmux by simply running it.

`tmux`

Then you run whatever command you need

`drush migrate [options]`

And you can now detach, (or close the window), with `CTRL+B D`, and you will be back to the terminal where you launched tmux.

List your running tmux sessions with `tmux ls`

If you didn't name your session, an advanced feature, it will just be called 0.

Re-attach with `tmux at -t 0`, and you'll be back to your drush command.

Tmux can do a lot more than this, but figuring that out is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I believe not. That is why Migrate supports a `reset` option migrations if they are orphaned or otherwise fail. Typically you run migrations as a shell user (yourself) on the system. Unless you're using something else to keep your processes alive -- they die when the terminal they're connected to die.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your drush jobs will continue across sessions, use the [screen](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen)
command.